# ElasticSearch advanced scoring with Nested Date Ranges and today > tomorrow > yesterday

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, scoring

Here's my data model in ES:

```
{
  id: 1,
  dateRanges: [
    { from: 2014-01-01, to: 2014-01-05 },
    { from: 2014-01-08, to: 2014-01-10 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I'd like to score my documents depending on the current date. PSEUDOCODE:

```
SCORE = 
  if( today IS IN any dateRange ) {
    return MAX_VALUE;
  } else if( today < any dateRange.from ) {
    dateRange.from = lowest dateRange.from, which is > today;
    return 1 / ( dateRange.from - today );
  } else {
    dateRange.to = highest dateRange.to, which is < today;
    return dateRange.to - today;
  }
```

---

### Example:

```
id | dateRange1               | dateRange2               | ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-10 | 2014-01-12 to 2014-01-13 | 
2  | 2014-01-03 to 2014-01-03 |                          |
3  | 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-02 | 2014-01-10 to 2014-01-15 |
```

`today = 2014-01-11`

The result should be in this order: 3 1 2

Reason:

- `3` gets the highest scoring because `today` is within at least one of the date ranges
- `1` gets the second highest scoring, because it has at least one date range where `dateRange.from > today`
- `2` gets the lowest scoring, because all of its date ranges have `dateRange.to < today`

---

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks for your help `:)`